# Firebase Authentication between multiple apps in the same project

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I have 2 apps inside the same Firebase project, one that has a login route that uses the signInWithEmailAndPassword and uses session persistence. In that app there is a button that routes to a different app in the same project, does firebase allow auth.currentUser to get the logged in user from the previous app or is a token from a backend app needed?